# header menu structure: cannot add additional menu items without alignment issues

Tags: menus, headers

When I add a new menu item to the header menu there is an alignment issue (please see the image).

I'm not exactly sure which part of the header.php file to modify to address this problem.

[image: header menu problem]

Update - below is the code from my theme header file:

```
<?php
global $gaming;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Streamer</title>
<!-- fav icon -->
<?php if($gaming['site_favicon_upload']['url']!=""){?>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $gaming['site_favicon_upload']['url'];?>"  
sizes="16x16">
<?php }?>

<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">
 <div class="header-main">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">   
     <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php 
 the_search_query(); ?>" /> 
     <input type="submit" placeholder="">
    </form>
   </div><!--col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <nav class="nav">
        <?php
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'nav',
                                    'menu_class'     => '',                                                                             
                                        'container'         => 'ul',
                                        'container_class' => '',
                                        'container_id'    => '',
                                 ) );
                            ?>
    </nav><!--nav-->
    <div class="logo">
     <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $gaming['site_logo_upload']['url'];?>" alt=""></a>
    </div><!--logo-->
   </div><!--col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 header-right">
    <a href="<?php echo $gaming['btn_url'];?>" class="btn">JOIN US NOW</a>
   </div><!--col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->
  </div><!--container-->
 </div><!--header-main-->
</header><!--header-->
```

Comment: Please share your menu and logo place code then i will try to help you

Comment: @Trilok Thank you, I have added the header file code to my post. If you could take a look that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use below code in your header.php file

```
<?php
global $gaming;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Streamer</title>
<!-- fav icon -->
<?php if($gaming['site_favicon_upload']['url']!=""){?>
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $gaming['site_favicon_upload']['url'];?>"  
sizes="16x16">
<?php }?>

<?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class();?>>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery(".nav ul > li:nth-child(2)").after('<div class="logo" ><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $gaming['site_logo_upload']['url'];?>" alt=""></a></div>');

}); 
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header">
 <div class="header-main">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
      <form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">   
     <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php 
 the_search_query(); ?>" /> 
     <input type="submit" placeholder="">
    </form>
   </div><!--col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <nav class="nav">
        <?php
                                wp_nav_menu( array(
                                    'theme_location' => 'nav',
                                    'menu_class'     => '',                                                                             
                                        'container'         => 'ul',
                                        'container_class' => '',
                                        'container_id'    => '',
                                 ) );
                            ?>
    </nav><!--nav--> 
   </div><!--col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 header-right">
    <a href="<?php echo $gaming['btn_url'];?>" class="btn">JOIN US NOW</a>
   </div><!--col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12-->
  </div><!--container-->
 </div><!--header-main-->
</header><!--header-->
```